# How to write an Elasticsearch Analyzer for address?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to write an analyzer for indexing an address field.
The field and the query can contain multiple combinations of city, country, street names/numbers, zip codes. Letter case and word order should be ignored. I also need to handle different languages. 
If I have an entry that contains "los angeles" -
currently I get it back with the query "los" or "angeles". but not "los angeles". I can't use the keyword tokenized because that would only search for matches on the full term... So how should I do it?
EDIT - this is for PREFIX search.
EDIT2 -
when I use the standard tokenizer - the search works for "los", "los angeles", "angeles", "angeles los" - but not for "lo" for example... I need the prefix search as well. If I use "match_phrase_prefix" instead of "prefix" query - I get "los ange" to work. But then word order has to be preserved... and adding numbers doesn't find matches.
For example if the field contains "los angeles 32" - "los 32" doesnt return it...

Thanks.

```
analysis: {
  analyzer: {
    phone_analyzer: {
      type: "custom",
      tokenizer: "keyword",
      filter: [
        "word_delimiter_for_phone"
      ]
    }
    address_analyzer: {
      type: "custom",
      tokenizer: "standard",
      filter: ["trim", "lowercase",'asciifolding']
    }
  },
  filter: {
    word_delimiter_for_phone: {
      type: "word_delimiter",
      catenate_numbers: true,
      preserve_original: true 
    }
  }
```

Comment: what about trying standard tokenizer?

Comment: its already standard - Im using the address analyzer

Comment: sorry, than i didn't get your problem. the problem is that you couldn't find los angeles?

Comment: Yep. I updated the question - this is a problem in prefix search...

Comment: when I use the standard tokenizer - the search works for "los", "los angeles", "angeles", "angeles los" - but not for "lo" for example... I need the prefix search as well.

Comment: This does however work on "match_phrase_prefix" instead of "prefix" query. But then word order has to be preserved...

Comment: okay lets rephrase it once again. you want words to be searchable by its prefix, like ang for angeles. also you want to search for 'ange lo' and get los angeles, right?

Comment: almost. "angele lo" = not that important for me, but "angeles lo" is... if that makes any difference.

Comment: @YossiChen - Did you manage to get this working as expected? I'm learning the whole ES way of doing things and trying to build an index that is suitable for address autocompletion / address lookup, I've spent the last week trying to learn different analyzers and custom settings along with ES docs but from a learners stand point its very overwhelming! I am hoping to gain some advice and help pointers prior to asking a S/O Question. Would be much appreciated if you could shed some advice on how you came to implement your functionality. Thanks